# How do I eliminate the call to http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml in my Adobe AIR application?

Tags: flash, air, adobe, policy, rsl

I have an Adobe AIR application and at a certain point it issues the warning:

Warning: Ignoring 'secure' attribute in policy file from http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml.  The 'secure' attribute is only permitted in HTTPS and socket policy files.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files for details.

I am not directly loading any external files at this point in the code.  I also have tried setting static-link-runtime-shared-libraries to true and that seems to make no difference.

I'd like to know what else might be causing this request, and how to eliminate it.  My application should be able to run without an internet connection, but this request is essentially blocking that ability.

Comment: It probably has something to do with updating the Flash Player, or something. It's annoying for me because my application runs on a HTTPS page but it connects to `fpdownload.adobe.com` via plain HTTP, causing a security "warning".

Comment: You are using RSLs signed by Adobe (swz). As they're signed, the runtime has to verify that they're valid and trusted, hence that petition. Check [viewing required RSLs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf674ba-7fff.html#WS19f279b149e7481c-152c7c012d9aabe32a-7ffd).
Have you tried to merge into code required libraries and SDK?
Are you loading any external library, pre-loading modules or sub-applications?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same error message, solved it by removing references to fonts that were not included in my asset.swf

Was running localy in FD 4.2.4, with parent.swf loading asset.swf as an asset library.
asset.swf had movieclips with textfields and fonts assigned as Font 1*, Font 2* etc., which were included in the library.
One of these textfields had a reference to "Times New Roman", which was not included.
Removing this textfield made everything work again!

Hope this helps anyone who has the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

In Flash Professional, this error may be because of the TLF texts...